# How to generate tasks for large groups in sharepoint online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, groups, tasks

Can someone tell me what is the best way to generate tasks for large group, for like 2000 people?

I have created a custom WF activity in Visual Studio, where I have CompositeTask component with expand groups property checked.

It is working well with small groups, but for large group the WF is stopping with error:

"RequestorId: acc05a50-253b-07da-0000-000000000000. Details: The workflow exceeded the maximum number of attempts to process a message."

I have to generate a simple task with mail for each user in the group, and end the WF with no waiting for complete the tasks.

Would it be working, if I manually expand the group and loop trough the users?
Or is it possible to do it with MS Flow or something?

Thanks for advices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is working well when I call REST service to get members of group,
and looping trough the users one by one, 
but only up to few hundred users, becouse workflow have limit 5000 request/ 24 hours.

Finaly I had to do it with powershell, becouse there are no limits.